# Limit httpd.exe CPU usage

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2008-r2, virtual-machines, cpu-usage, subversion-edge

We are using Collabnet Subversion Edge in one of our VMs, and occasionally one of the httpd.exe processes spikes to ~100% and just sits there. I believe it's interfering with our overnight backup amongst other daily operations. Is there a way I can limit the CPU usage of Apache? I'd like to either limit the CPU usage to a certain percentage or start it as a low priority process if this is possible, without having to lower the priority in the Task Manager.

The Apache version with Subversion Edge we have is 2.2.23 (Win64), and Subversion Server is SVN/1.7.8 DAV/2

Answer (score 1):

Windows System Resource Manager.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755056.aspx